# Cocoapods not working Xcode 9.2

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode9.2

Cocoapods are installed but not working(Xcode 9.2),

[image]

I tried these solutions  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3777. I have set **Framework set paths** to **recursive** but nothing is working for me. Even in framework directory its showing multiple files, find the below image

[image]

Comment: update your pod, then check

Comment: Tried `pod install`?

Comment: Sorry didn't work.

Comment: try building the workspace

Comment: Just to check; have you tried `pod deintegrate` followed by `pod install`?

Comment: @Hodson Yes the first thing.

Comment: Are you opening the xcworkspace file and not the project? Just making sure :)

Comment: @donnywals opening xcworkspace only

Comment: @donnywals PaulBeusterien Hodson,  I removed all the pods and installed only Alamofire its working, when I add other pods that time its showing error. Any solution based on this?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. In your project setting goto build setting and set `Build Active Architecture only`-> **Yes**. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Ohk update like that-->>>  sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin

Comment: Delete your derived Data from the Xcode, Force quite xcode  and restart your mac.

Comment: I removed all the pods and installed only Alamofire its working, when I add other pods that time its showing error. Any solution based on this

Comment: check the first image "No such module"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try this

```
pod repo update
```

Comment: I removed all the pods and installed only Alamofire its working, when I add other pods that time its showing error. Any solution based on this?