# Error "No such module" when import framework in Swift file

Tags: ios, swift

I've imported a framework file to my project
I created 2 files in Xcode project which import it :
**Drawing.swift**

```
import Foundation
import WILLCore

class DrawingView: NSObject {

}
```

**Drawing.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <WILLCore/WILLCore.h>
@interface TestFW : NSObject


@end
```

But it gives an error:`No such module 'WILLCore'` in Swift file. The Objective-C file is built fine. What happens with this framework?

[image]

Please help!

Comment: @matt Sorry, I updated my code. Both are not working

Comment: @matt Why it happen only in Swift file? I've add path in **Framework Search Paths** before

Comment: I don't know what you've done. You didn't give any information. All I know is that this question has been discussed here before and your repetition of the same question adds nothing to the mix.

Comment: Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49856678/cocoapods-not-working-xcode-9-2/49858471#49858471

Comment: @kalpesh `Build Active Architecture only` Debug is set to YES by default

Comment: check my comments on answer Might be it will help you.

Comment: @kalpesh Sorry because I'm newbie in this. My project doesn't use pod, just add framework file to project.

Comment: I've check  **Framework Search Paths** in Project setting, and **Embedded Binaries**, **Linked Framework and Libraries** in Target setting too

Comment: Is your project in swift right?

Comment: Yes, I created new project with Swift language

Comment: Should I create the Objective-C bridge header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169320/discussion-between-quangkid-and-kalpesh).